# NextJS static export dynamic paths with app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, routes, capacitor

I have a page set up in the directory `src/app/c/patient/[id]/page.tsx`

It works perfectly fine when deployed but I wanted to also export it to a js bundle to use with the Capacitor Android/iOS app. I get the error:

`Error: Page "/c/patient/[id]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.`

So I added:

```
export async function generateStaticParams(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve([]);
    });
}
```

However that didn't work, I still saw the same error, this is the full file:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export const metadata = {
    title: 'Patient',
};

type Props = {
    params: {
        id: string;
    };
};

export async function generateStaticParams(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve([]);
    });
}

export default function PatientPage({ params }: Props) {
    const { id } = params;


    return <PatientProfileView patientUserId={id as string}/>;
}
```

I'm not sure why it's failing when the function is there, but I also wanted to know if I do get it working will the routes still work dynamically (i.e. will `const { id } = params` get me the /[id] part of the URL in a static export?

Comment: I am having the same problem with Next.js 14, but every discussion I can find on this issue is concerning Next.js 13 and almost always involves people simply forgetting to include this function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem/solution. When running `next dev`, your code will work fine. But to make it also work with static builds, you need to modify your `resolve([])` to `resolve([{ id: 'whatever }])`.

You must have at least one object in that returned array, and you should additionally ensure that each object contains all the required props expected by the component.

(The error message from the next CLI is a bit unhelpful, as one might interpret it as saying that you forgot to export the method altogether.)

Also, FYI, because the function is already marked async, you don't need to return a promise, and instead can return the array directly, like so:

```js
export async function generateStaticParams(): Promise<any> {
    return [{ id: 'whatever' }];
}
```